# Функция неправильно экранирует кавычки из элементов, как можно это сделать?

Tags: javascript, строки, csv

```js
function arrayToCsv(data) {
  let result = data
    .map((array) =>
      array
        .map((e) => {
          let type = typeof e;
          if (type !== "number" && type !== "string")
            throw new Error("Unexpected value");
          //
          if (type === "string" && e.includes(",")) {
            return JSON.stringify(e);
          } else return e;
        })
        .join(",")
    )
    .join("\n");
  return result;
}
```

Функция, которая переводит двумерный массив (массив массивов) в CSV формат и возвращает строку. Кавычки должны становиться двойными. Код должен корректно экранировать кавычки, в тестах выдает ошибку.
Expected: """"text""","other ""long"" text""
Received: ""text",other "long" text"

```
  55 |   it('корректно экранирует кавычки', () => {
  56 |     const data1 = [['"text"', 'other "long" text']];
> 57 |     expect(arrayToCsv(data1)).toBe('"""text""","other ""long"" text"');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы функция проверяла элемент на наличие кавычек и удваивала их при наличии, причем сам элемент тоже должен быть обернут в кавычки

Comment: Добавьте проверку. Для справки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377454/escaping-tricky-string-to-csv-format.

Comment: Можете подсказать куда ее добавить и какую

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayToCsv(data) {


let result = data
    .map((array) =>
      array
        .map((e) => {


  let type = typeof e;
      if (type !== "number" && type !== "string")
        throw new Error("Unexpected value");

      return type === "string" && e.length > 1
        ? '"' + e.replace(/\"/g, '""') + '"'
        : e;
    })
    .join(",")
)
.join("\n");
  return result;
}
```